# What does this equation mean in context of RF trace length?

Tags: rf, antenna

I came across another [Phil's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdUZ2IjO9do) on YouTube. However, he did not explain this part in great detail. What does Lcritical mean in terms of the RF trace length?

The Lcritical had to do with the trace length from the STM32WB MCU RF pin (this is a Bluetooth MCU) to the matching network (pi filter).

[image]

Comment: "Video Unavailabl", also, who is Phil?

Comment: @MarcusMüller "@PhilsLab" on YouTube. In terms of the link, that is very weird it is now unavailable.

Comment: Never heard of that. Does he work with a textbook, or is there a scriptum, or do you have to note all the equations off the screen?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I note the equations I am unsure of and try and get assistance on this platform. However with the video not available I cannot give more context than that. Should I remove my post, or do you have enough info to proceed with an answer?

Comment: You could try telling us what the context was! Like, was this about stub length some lumped element oscillator, where *criticality* has a meaning? Maybe: Or was this about the length at which you need to take a trace into account?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Please see update. "Or was this about the length at which you need to take a trace into account" It was about the trace length from the MCU RF pin to the input into the pi filter (matching network)

Comment: I'm guessing that he's (Phil) saying you don't have worry about the impedance of that trace if it's shorter than Lcritical.  But that's just a guess based on the limited information provided.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, then this is *probably* about how long you can make a trace, before you need to consider it a transmission line of its own (which would require matching of its own).

The idea here *seems* to be that a line shorter than 1/12 of a wavelength effectively is always at the source-induced potential at any point (not too much happens over a distance of 1/12 of a sine period, so the mismatch at the short piece of trace's end will reflect, yes, but the reflection will instantly get "compensated" by the thing feeding the line).

Why 1/12? Because: well. That's a choice you make. (or that author made). This number might be larger for things where a mismatch matters less (for example, if there's some limited self-tuning capability at one of the ends), or lower if it really matters (e.g. when a that mismatch would convert a small fraction of RF power to heat, that's going to be a problem if your RF transmitter has 10 kW: a "small fraction" can quickly mean "glowing red"; or, of course, if you're building a measurement device).